# .net deserialize xml with dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I've got a problem during deserialization of xml files with .net. I've got a bunch of xml files and want to deserialize them to matching classes generated from XSDs.

But I don't know, which of those XML files contains serialized objects from which class:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<foo xmlns="http://foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://foo">
</foo>
```

According c# class looks like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.3081.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://Foo")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://foo", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Foo {
}
```

I want to determine XMLs type during runtime. Is there any way to do this? (Except checking root elements and determine the right type by myself)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "Except checking root elements and determine the right type by myself" eeeh, no. You **have** to give the seralizer some information about what you want to de-serialize. You can´t just say: here´s an xml, create whatever you want from it.

Comment: What do you mean by `XMLs type`? As in the type of object that will be created on deserialization? And, `determine the right type by myself` as opposed to what? automatically using code?

Comment: But the serializer should be capable of doing this? He has all namespaces from the XML itself and i can provide all possible classes (and there a namespace matching attributes included). 

So basically looking for a way to match XMLs namespace with the namespace attribute within the .net classes, which is sufficient to determine which class is assigned to which class.